# Do Heroku Scheduler tasks cost money?

Tags: process, heroku, scheduler

I've been reading through Heroku's documentation but just found it plain confusing.  I have an app up that has both a web-based front-end (with web process) and a task that's set to run every day at midnight by Heroku Scheduler (shows up on `heroku ps` as `run.1`).

So, my `heroku ps` looks like this:

```
Process  State       Command
-------  ----------  ------------------------------------
run.1    up for 21h  python webpage/listings.py
web.1    up for 8m   python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0..
```

What I'm trying to figure out is, is this considered two dynos?  Is the `run` task considered a background task?

**Main question: Will this cost money?**

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not concerned about paying Heroku for services, I'm just trying to understand the pricing model and how dynos work.

Comment: Note that the billing system explained in the answers has changed. The 750-free-hours are considered now [legacy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/legacy-dynos). Current billing system can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, a [Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) will accrue usage and will cost money if you go over your [750 free dyno-hours](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing#750-free-dyno-hours-per-app) you are given per app each month. As long as you keep within that limit, you won't be charged.

[Scheduler runs one-off dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#dyno-hour-costs), which accrue usage just like regular dynos. They will appear with a “scheduler” dyno type in your Heroku invoice.

Comment: Indeed they are two dynos, the difference being that (presumably) the dyno spun up by the Heroku Scheduler will only run for a short amount of time whereas your `web` dyno is continuously running. So the `run` dyno will only count (in your above example) for the 21 minutes it's running. Often you will be able to run these short, periodic, tasks and stay within your 750 free dyno-hours per month even alongside an always-on `web` dyno.

Comment: @Ryan Daigle: So, to sum up, One web dyno (which is always up, as it is able to respond to web requests all the time), uses 720 or 744 hours a month (depending if there is 30 or 31 day in the month). So you still have 6 free hours remaining. If you run a daily scheduler task that last in average for 10 minutes, this will only use a worker dyno for a little over 5 hours a month (10*31/60), am I correct?

Comment: @RyanDaigle: Would I charged by Heroku if the dyno processing my scheduler tasks is idle? Does it go to terminate from idleon it's own and then wakes up when there is scheduled task? I'm confused with this one-off dyno charging concept.

Comment: @JatinGanhotra Your one-off dynos terminate when their process exits. So.. as long as the process in your dyno terminates when it's done the dyno will only live for that period of time and you won't be charged for any other period of time (i.e. you won't be charged between runs since there's no dyno provisioned).

Comment: Comments helped more than the answer.

Comment: I recently had to pay for my scheduler whereas I did not have to before. I realized only later that I had changed the code so that it would loop continuously (instead of being fired up every 10 minutes). Hence the charge.

Comment: @RyanDaigle, this seems to imply that, unlike Amazon, Heroku does not count a full hour for any usage within the hour.  Is this correct?

Comment: @EricWalker - correct, Heroku dynos are pro-rated to the second

Comment: Note that the billing system in Heroku has changed. The 750-free-hours are considered now [legacy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/legacy-dynos). Current billing system can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing)

Answer (score 4):

There is 750 of free hours.

In the billing, dynos are divided in four groups: worker (background dynos), web dynos, rake and one-off-process (when executing "heroku run", for example used by the scheduler).

More at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing